# How can WCF client detect that server requires security certificate?

Tags: wcf-security, x509certificate

How can WCF client detect that server requires security certificate? The detection should happen at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I have in mind to resolve such issue it will be to connect to that server and call a method or something like that. Put the server call in a try-catch block and read the message at runtime.

For example, I tried this in a application of mine which connected with a server with security certificates, deleting the part for certificates in my clients. I had an error like this:

`The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.`

So if this Exception is caught, you can detect at runtime that the server requires security certificate.

There may be more Exception messages for this problem. Also, I don't know if it is the best way. But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that up front (design time). There is no foolproof way to know this at runtime (you could guess from an error message but this is not a good idea.)
If it is required to decide this only at runtime then client and server must agree on their own protocol to communicate this (e.g. an operation IsCertRequired).